# Unterschied zwischen »Art«, »Weise« und »Methode«

Tags: difference

Mir scheint, als hätten die Wörter *Art, Weise* und *Methode* ähnliche Bedeutungen. Trotzdem will ich den geringen Unterschied wissen.

Comment: Erbsenzähler: Sie klingen nicht ähnlich, sie haben eine ähnliche Bedeutung

Comment: Ähnlichkeiten im Klang liegen überhaupt keine vor. Da ich davon ausgehe, dass der Fragesteller vermutlich eher Ähnlichkeiten in der Bedeutung gemeint hat, habe ich die Frage entsprechend editiert.

Comment: Ein Beispielsatz: "Die Art und Weise des Vorgehens hat Methode."

Answer (score 5):

### Art

Dieses Wort hat sehr viele Bedeutungen. [Woxikon](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/art.php) führt es in 58 verschiedenen Synonymgruppen auf, die sich in ihren Bedeutungsfeldern aber teilweise stark überlappen.

Das [Digitale Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache (DWDS)](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Art) macht wesentlich gröbere Klassifizierungen und kommt auf nur vier Bedeutungen, nämlich:

1. **Weise, Verhaltensweise** (meist im Singular)

   > Die **Art** zu sprechen.
   >   Jemand hat eine gewinnende **Art.**
   >   Die **Art**, die Wolfgang heute an den Tag legt, ist ziemlich überheblich.

   - In Verbindung mit *auf*

     > etwas **auf** eine bestimmte **Art** machen
     >   jemandem etwas **auf** schonende **Art** beibringen
   - In Verbindung mit *in*

     > etwas **in** gewohnter **Art** machen
     >   **in** einer bestimmten **Art** sprechen
   - In Verbindung mit *nach*

     > **nach Art** der Affen klettern
   - Verstärkung durch das Synonym *Weise*

     > seine **Art und Weise** gefällt mir nicht
     >   eine Umstandsbestimmung der **Art und Weise**
2. **richtiges, gutes Benehmen** (nur im Singular)
   häufig verneint oder in Frage gestellt:

   > Jemanden so zu behandeln ist wirklich keine **Art.**
   >   Ist das eine **Art**, jemanden so zu behandeln?
3. **Beschaffenheit, Natur** (häufig im Singular)

   > Das entspricht nicht seiner **Art.**
   >   Wir kommen nun zu Fragen allgemeiner **Art.**
   >   Vorfälle dieser **Art** kommen selten vor.
4. **Sorte**

   > Die genau Zahl der **Arten** innerhalb der Gattung der Pferde ist umstritten.
   >   Diese **Art** ist bereits ausgestorben.
   >   Unsere Tochter schlägt ein wenig aus der **Art.**
   >   Möbel aller **Art**
   >   Ilse scheut jede **Art** von Veränderung.
   >   Die Masse bildete eine **Art** Teppich auf dem Boden.
   >   Seine Geste war wohl eine **Art** von Gruß.

---

### Weise

[Woxikon](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/weise.php) listet dieses Wort in 30 Synonymgruppen auf, das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Weise) unterscheidet nur zwei Bedeutungen:

1. **die Form bzw. Art wie etwas geschieht**

   > Auf diese Weise gelangte Walter zu mehr Geld.
   >   Der Kontrollor prüfte den Fahrschein auf die übliche Weise.
   >   Ich hatte auf allerlei Weise mit ihm zu tun.

   - Verstärkung durch das Synonym *Art*

     > seine **Art und Weise** gefällt mir nicht.
     >   Die **Art und Weise** seiner Gestik ist einzigartig.
2. **Melodie, kleines Musikstück**

   > Erwin pfiff eine fröhliche **Weise** vor sich hin als er über die Felder wanderte.
   >   Die alten Weisen singt heute kaum noch jemand.

---

### Methode

[Woxikon](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/methode.php) kennt 31 Synonymgruppen, zu denen das Wort *Methode* gehört, das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Methode) kennt nur diese eine Bedeutung:

- **planmäßiges Verfahren, System von Regeln**

  > Es gibt wissenschaftliche, physikalische, mathematische und viele andere **Methoden.**
  >   Studenten lernen die spezifischen **Methoden** ihres Faches.
  >   Erika hat eine neue **Methode** zur Herstellung von Kaugummi entwickelt.
  >   Der Inspektor vertraute lieber auf die alten **Methoden.**
  >   Das sind die **Methoden** eines Kriminellen.
  >   Seine Arbeit, sich immer nach vorne zu schummeln, hat **Methode.**

---

### Fazit

Die Bedeutung 1 des Wortes *»Art«* ist ein Synonym der Bedeutung 1 des Wortes *»Weise«*, die beide sogar oftmals zusammen verwendet werden um sich gegenseitig zu verstärken (*»Art und Weise«*).

Dieselbe Bedeutung hat auch Ähnlichkeiten mit der Bedeutung des Wortes *»Methode«*, aber zu Bedeutung von *»Methode«* gehört auch ein Plan oder eine Absicht, der/die der Handlung zugrunde liegt. Ein solcher Plan bzw. eine solche Absicht sind kein Teil der Bedeutung von *»Art«* und *»Weise«*.

Comment: Gute Antwort, aber bei *Wixikon* habe ich gestutzt. Tippfehler oder Seitenhieb?

Comment: @Philipp: Tippfehler. O ind I liegen auf der Tastatur direkt nebeneinander, und die Rechtschreibprüfung hält auch den korrekten Namen für falsch, daher beachtete ich es nicht weiter, als das Wort rot unterstrichen war.

Comment: Dank schön.Sie erklären ein deutlich